# Scilab execstr csvRead in the loop

Tags: arrays, string, scilab

I tested following function in Scilab 6.1 and 2023.1. I try to read all `*.txt` files in a folder one by one and load it to a matrix.

```
datfiles=ls('*.txt','r');// List all *.txt Files in datfiles
for i = 1:size(datfiles, 1) // for each *.txt file
    token=strtok(datfiles(i,:),'.'); // save name of each txt.file and... 
    
    // execstr(token + '=csvRead('+ string(datfiles(i,:)) + ', ascii(9), [], ''string'')'); // use the name of the .txt file as variable name, where as all data is saved.
    
    execstr('csvRead('+ string("StepPo135.txt")+')'); //
end
```

I still get following error. By the way. How can I  change this output to english? My preferences are set to english

*bei Zeile     1 von ausgeführtem String

Versuch, ein Feld in einem nicht strukturierten Array zu referenzieren.*

**Error: Try, reference one field in not a stuctured array**

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
datfiles=ls('*.txt');// List all *.txt Files in datfiles
for i = 1:size(datfiles, 1) // for each *.txt file
    token=strtok(datfiles(i,:),'.'); // save name of each txt.file and... 
    execstr(token+"=csvRead("""+datfiles(i,:)+""", ascii(9), [], ''string'')"); 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes or double quotes by doubling them, like this

```
datfile="StepPo135.txt";
execstr("token=csvRead("""+datfile+""")")
```

The error message is due to Scilab trying to interpret `StepPo135.txt` without the quotes, i.e. as if you were trying to extract the `txt` field of `StepPo135` considered as a struct.

Comment: Thanks again! "token" is string that changes every loop and creates a new variable each loop. Thanky to you , I got it running:

datfiles=ls('*.txt');// List all *.txt Files in datfiles
for i = 1:size(datfiles, 1) // for each *.txt file
    token=strtok(datfiles(i,:),'.'); // save name of each txt.file and... 
    execstr(token+"=csvRead("""+datfiles(i,:)+""", ascii(9), [], ''string'')"); 
end